# Want to change the Rect Transform of GameObject (Button) on canvas unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on learning how to use Unity and have been unable to solve this problem of mine. I am currently working on a prototype of a game and need to change the RectTransform Pos X to a value that I want.

However, so far I was unable to do it. I tried Vector2 and Vector3 converations but I can't seem to get it right.

Here is what I have atm (I know the new RectTransform is doing nothing, bu I am simply out of ideas.):

```
void Start()
{
    changeTransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("NextButton").GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    changeTransform = new RectTransform();
}
```

And all I want is to set the Pos X of the rect transform to be 25.
[image]

Anything helps. Thanks a lot.

EDIT:
When I change the value of the Pos X in the inspector it gets overwritten back to the value seen in the picture.

EDIT2:
Below is how my buttons look right now. I just want the Next-Button to be aligned with the other buttons on the left side without it chaning its size.
[image]

Comment: If you want to change values on a component then you'd write something like `changeTransform.position = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);` instead of `changeTransform = new RectTransform();`

Comment: I tried it before. But it did not work that way.

Comment: What in the world is this supposed to do `changeTransform = new RectTransform()`? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you want to achieve

> I just want the Next-Button to be aligned with the other buttons on the left side without it chaning its size.

simply wrap your `NextButton` under another object

```
- NextButtonContainer
  |-- NextButton
```

=> make `NextButton` be left aligned within the `NextButtonContainer`

Now the `NextButtonContainer` can simply grow like the other buttons, have no visual components at all and allow the next button to be left aligned within it and have a fixed size

Answer (score 0):

I can see that some properties of the Rect Transform component are being overridden by the Content Size Fitter component.
You should remove the Content Size Fitter component from the GameObject or set the horizontal and vertical fit in this component to unconstrained. If this doesn't work, please let me know of what other components are attached to this GameObject.

Comment: The Content Size Fitter component is on the button. However, if I remove it, it simply makes my button to big (Since it is on a Panel that uses a Vertical Layout Group. Am I not able to overwrite it through the code?